# SugarCRM 5 - Create a sub-panel for invoices in Account Panel

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

I'm customizing a SugarCRM 5, and in my **SugarCRM database** I have all invoices which were imported from our ERP. Now, I would like to know if it is possible to create a new sub-panel in the Accounts Panel **without editing the original SugarCRM files**, so that my client invoices index are visible in that interface.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked, you could use the [module builder](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/tutorials/Customizing_Sugar/4/) to extend the interface. From 5.0 (or maybe 4.x) on, Sugar added all those APIs, which should enable you to extend SugarCRM without hacking it in and losing it with the next upgrade.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new module - Invoices using Module Builder and then add relations between Accounts and Invoices. The subpanels will appear for both - Accounts and Invoices without any coding. You should just customize the columns again using Module Builder.

Answer (score 1):

as stated above, create invoices module to hold all your invoices, but before doing import make relationship with accounts and map the account field when importing so the invoice is automatically connect in subpanel and shown

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the Account name should be a related field in your new invoices module (base the module creation on something like QUOTES that has similar fields. Once you create the module (so simple you can almost guess your way through it in the ADMIN section) and the fields you like (using Studio) just add the RELATED field Account Name and the sub-panel will be established in your ACCOUNTS module and the invoice will magically populate, especially if you re-install them using the import feature from a CSV file (spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can create sub-panels in account modules details view by just giving relationship within two modules. Create a one-to-many relationship from Account module to Invoices module.